# Mysql query mixing date time and position

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT message_text 
FROM messages 
WHERE message_date >= '$connection_time'
```

Simple enough.
This allows me to retrieve messages being posted since the connection time.

But I also need to retrieve the last 15 messages posted before that connection time.
(The best would be to do this all with a single query).

How would I do that?

PS: I thought about getting the id of the first message retrieved and subtract 15 of it but it only works if the id's are consecutive which is not always the case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the following query to your existing one with [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html):

```
SELECT   message_text
FROM     messages
WHERE    message_date < '$connection_time'
ORDER BY message_date DESC
LIMIT    15
```

By the way, I really really really hope that you're **absolutely certain** `$connection_time` has been stripped of any potential SQL injection attacks (if you don't know what that means, go and read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)).  You ought to use prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. About the injection: the value is not generated by the user but by a function as soon as the user connects. So there is no interference with any user input at this point. Am I thinking straight? When I get user input and need to query with it, I verify that the data is compliant with what it should be (numbers only etc..)

Comment: So long as you trust your function, yes.  But it's good discipline to use parameterised queries anyway (so you don't forget that time when you *are* handling user data); also, I like to put the warning whenever I see variables embedded in SQL for the benefit of any other readers.

Comment: I get your point but the variable as you see it there, unless it's a generated one, is always prepared before using it. I just don't like to strip it inside the query, for clarity sake. For the example it is generated by a simple date() function. I believe it can be trusted.I really thank you for your concern. You are right. Someone who doesn't know how to union is generally likely to make this kind of mistakes :-)